# mysql workbench not connecting with localhost on mac, Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1 (49)

Tags: mysql, database, localhost, mysql-workbench

I'm starting up with mysql on mac. I have installed Mysql and mysql workbench. My mysql server is running. When I try test connection with mysql workbench I get **Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (49)**. When I try to connect with terminal it works perfectly. In terminal I use the command `mysql -u root -p` then enter the password. I can't seem to figure this out, do I need to add something in my.cnf file ? Currently it says

```
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

I can't find what (49) means in the error too. Thanks in advance. I'm using MacOS Mojave, mysql server version 8.0.17

[image]

**EDIT :** I reinstalled my MacOS, it started working. Guess some issue with some internal file.

Comment: From `/usr/include/sys/errno.h`: `#define EADDRNOTAVAIL 49  /* Can't assign requested address */`

Comment: It's not a very enlightening error, though.

Comment: Try using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I've changed both the addresses to localhost, stopped the server then started again, still not working. I've also tried creating a new user and using that in workbench. But still no good.

Comment: also tried ```mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306```, it gives **ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (49)**

Comment: When connecting to localhost it normally uses a Unix domain socket, not TCP/IP. So the question is how to get MySQL Workbench to connect using that method.

Comment: I was not able to figure it out, I just had to soft format my MacBook. Maybe there was a problem with some packages I installed.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Connection Method` menu to `Local Socket/Pipe`.

Leave the "Socket/Pipe Path" field empty to use the default socket. This is equivalent to omitting the `-h` option when using the `mysql` command line client.

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-socket.html)

Comment: When I do this I get **Failed to Connect to MySQL using local socket/pipe at "default path" with user root** **Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (49)**. Another thing is is my mysql pane in system preferences, when I go to configuration, the configuration file is unselected. I tried to select it and give the path of my.cnf file. But still no good.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use MySQL Workbench or run MySQL locally on my Mac, so this is beyond my expertise.